SSH into a router - connected off main company WiFi
I am setting up a test environment where it is necessary to switch a WiFi router off and on from within test software. The current set up is:

Archer A23 (192.168.0.1) is the Main WiFi router. Development computers all attach to this. This router is on all the time!
A crappy NetComm Wireless router, which we will switch on and off during tests.
Ubiquiti Edge Router (192.168.1.1) is connected between the Archer A23 & Netcomm. eth0 on Edge Router connected to Archer A23 (internet) on IP 192.168.0.188 eth1 on Edge Router used as direct connection during set up (SSH) on IP 192.168.1.10 eth2 on Edge Router connected to NetComm Wireless Router.
The problem I am experiencing is that I can not successfully SSH into the Edge Router from a development PC which is connected to the Archer A23 (the main WiFi router). The purpose of which is to switch the NetComm WiFi router off and on again. While I can connect to the Edge Router over ethernet, that is not possible during the tests, as the computer driving the tests will not be physically near the routers, and will be entangled in a mass of other test equipment. It's just not a workable solution! So, I really need to have Wireless access to the Edge Router over SSH.
I have gone through the quick start for the Edge Router and connected it to the Archer on eth0 as expected. On the Edge Router, I have "manually" selected the IP address for the Archer A23 as 192.168.0.188. And then on the Archer A23, I have reserved that IP for the Edge Router, configuring it by MAC address.
When I directly connect a test PC to eth1 on the Edge Router, with the ethernet adaptor on the PC configured with IP4 IP = 192.168.1.10, I can SSH onto the Edge Router no problem.
However, from a normally connected computer, I can not ping 192.168.1.1 unless connected over ethernet. I am not a network engineer, and while I imagine this is an extremely basic problem, it appears to one I can not solve.

You probably have your Edge Router doing NAT (NAPT) gatewaying instead of being a plain old IP-forwarding router. So to reach the Edge Router from the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet (the Archer A24's LAN subnet, that your development laptop is on), you must SSH to the Edge Router's IP address that is reachable from your laptop, which would be the 192.168.0.188 address that the Edge Router has on eth0.
If you're sure your Edge Router is not doing NAT, then your dev laptop probably doesn't know, and can't discover, a route from the laptop's home subnet of 192.168.0.0/24, to the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet you were previously trying to SSH to. You could solve this by putting a static route in your laptop's route table (telling your laptop that 192.168.0.188 is the gateway by which to reach the single IP address 192.168.1.1, or the whole subnet 192.168.1.0/24). Or you could put that static route in the Archer A24's route table, if you have a way to do that.
Or if you wanted to be fancy and your equipment is sophisticated enough to support it, you could set up a routing protocol so that the routers can inform each other about which subnets can be reached where, so their route tables automatically stay up to date. But that's probably overkill for such a simple network.
